# -gt: unary operator expected error on bash

Tags: bash

I wrote this simple script:

```
i = "1";
b = "4";
if [ "$i"-gt "$b" ]
then
echo ""
fi
```

But I got this error on attempting to run it:

```
[: -gt: unary operator expected
```

What is wong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide complete error listings as you ask ;-)

```
The program 'i' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install iprint
b: command not found
bash: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

This has only subtle differences, but works; study it:

```
i="1";
b="4";
if [ "$i" -gt "$b" ]
then
  echo "Greater"
else
  echo "NOT Greater"
fi
```

1. `i = "1"` is interpreted by bash to be run `i` with the parameters `=` and `"1"`.
2. `"$i"` is has not been set to anything due to 1), i.e. it is `""` (null string) - the same with `"$b"`

This makes `[ "$i"-gt "$b" ]` read as `[ -gt ]` as interpretation comes to that point. Also note that as you fix 1) you still have the issue of 'no space' between `"$i"` and `-gt`